# how to force ansible to use python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ansible

I am running `CentOS7`.  I have installed `dnf`and updated the default version on Centos to `python3`.  I have added the `ansible_python_interpreter=/bin/python3` on the inventory.  Still when I run `ansible -- version` it still says `python2.7`.  I have also done a `yum` erase ansible and then a `dnf`install `ansible`.  Finally I uninstalled ansible and installed it via `pip3 install ansible`.  Even after doing all this my version of python is still `2.7`.  What am I missing to get ansible to use python3 as it's default version?

Comment: can you do `ls -lrt /bin/python3` and share the output ?

Comment: also `printenv |grep -i ansible`

Comment: Make sure you did not previously install ansible through pip in python2. Remove from python2 if it exists. Alternatively, use a python3 virtualenv to install and run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to expand on @colyn1337 answer
I showed some sample code that works for me. This path is on my MAC but find out where your Python3 resides and point it to that directory.

```
---                                                                         
 - name: load files from AWS S3 bucket
   hosts: localhost
   connection: local
   become: true
   vars:
     ansible_python_interpreter: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3
   tasks:
```

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/python_3_support.html#using-python-3-on-the-managed-machines-with-commands-and-playbooks) which instruct on how to configure the python interpreter with the following variable:

`ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3`

If you're using AWX you can create a group in your inventory which represents your python 3 hosts and set the variable at the group level.  Or you can do it in global vars, or in the playbooks themselves.

There's some prerequisite work to do to enable python 3 in ansible.  It's covered in the doc linked above.

Comment: If you want to do this via your command use `-e ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3`